# Storm Tweet-How to run

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter, apache-storm

first of all sorry if the question could be stupid, but I'm a beginner in both java and storm.

For an important assignment I should complete a code in java for a streaming analysis on twitter.
I'm trying to modify  this code :

https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch04-spouts/tree/master/src/main/java/twitter/streaming

After all my changes I would like to run and check the work....but I don't know how .

Until now I used to running with the command in the window of Eclipse, but now there is this line in the file downloaded:

To run this topology you should execute this main as: 
 ***java -cp theGeneratedJar.jar twitter.streaming.Topology < track > < twitterUser > < twitterPassword > ***

I should create a simple jar file or a runnable one? I know the command java -cp to run the script by the terminal, but , considering the password=1234 and user=1234@gmail.com, what should be exactly the line to run the code?

Every time that I try , i get always this error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Final**
this is my line:

java -cp Test.jar (jar file name) Final (main class) home/.../test.jar (file path) 1234@gmail.com (twitter user) 1234 (password)

sorry again if the question could seem trivial

regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure your **pom.xml** to make a jar file with dependencies (update the *build* section):

   ```
   <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.2</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.6</source>
               <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <descriptorRefs>
                   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>make-assembly</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>single</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
2. Build the project:

   **mvn clean install**
3. Run topology (the jar file with the dependencies):

   **java -cp target/Spouts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar twitter.streaming.Topology** *track* *1234@gmail.com* *1234*